# Get max change between rows, ignoring empty cells at end of list

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet where I'm tracking my net worth over time. Once a month, I add in my account balances.

In one sheet, I have this structure:

| Date | Year | Net Worth | Account1 | Account2 | Account3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan 31, 2021 | 2021 | $320 | $200 | $140 | -$20 |
| Feb 28, 2021 | 2021 | $340 | $200 | $150 | -$10 |
| Mar 31, 2021 | 2021 | $410 | $250 | $200 | -$40 |
| Apr 30, 2021 |  |  |  |  |  |
| May 31, 2021 |  |  |  |  |  |

...rest of months for the year

The formula in the Year column is `=if(C3<>"", year(A3), "")`.

The formula in the Net worth column is `=if(sum(D3:F3)<>0, sum(D3:F3), "")`.

**The Problem:**
I'd like to have a cell which lists the greatest 1 month change (so $410 - $340 = $70), without having to update the formula every month. (In an ideal world, I never need to touch it again, only ever having to enter account balances once a month.)

**What I've got so far:**

```
=if(
  abs(min(ArrayFormula(C3:C400 - C2:C399)))=max(ArrayFormula(abs(C3:C400 - C2:C399))), 
  min(ArrayFormula(C3:C400 - C2:C399)),
  max(ArrayFormula(C3:C400 - C2:C399))
)
```

However, this includes the change from $410 to `""`, which is coerced to $0. So instead of the expected $70, I'm instead getting $410.

How can I get the greatest 1 month change, but ignore the empty string values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to fix it is just to put in an if clause I think:

```
=ArrayFormula(max(if(C3:C400<>"",abs(C3:C400-C2:C399),)))
```

because Max will ignore the empty string generated by the If statement

or slightly shorter:

```
=ArrayFormula(max((C3:C400<>"")*abs(C3:C400-C2:C399)))
```

so that the change for any empty cells is set to zero.

These assume that C2 itself is not blank!